# Why does std::regex_match not support "zero-length assertions"?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, standards

```
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    b = std::regex_match("building", std::regex("^\w*uild(?=ing$)"));
    //
    // b is expected to be true, but the actual value is false.
    //
}
```

My compiler is clang 3.8.

Why does std::regex_match not support "zero-length assertions"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[regex_match](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) is only for matching the ***entire*** input string. Your regex — written correctly as `"^\\w*uild(?=ing$)` with the backslash escaped, or as a [raw string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) `R"(^\w*uild(?=ing$))"` — only actually matches (consumes) the prefix `build`. It looks ahead for `ing$`, and will successfully find it, but since the whole input string wasn't consumed, regex_match rejects the match.

If you want to use regex_match but only capture the first part, you could use `^(\w*uild)ing$` (or just `(\w*uild)ing` since the whole string must be matched) and access the 1st capture group.

But since you're using `^` and `$` anyway, you might as well use [regex_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) instead:

```
int main()
{
    std::cmatch m;
    if (std::regex_search("building", m, std::regex(R"(^\w*uild(?=ing$))"))) {
        std::cout << "m[0] = " << m[0] << std::endl;  // prints "m[0] = build"
    }
    return 0;
}
```